# Multiple pages share a master page

Tags: angularjs, html, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, vue.js

I'm working on an asp.net web api project, where Default.html calls certain web api endpoints.

Now I need to add another page, specifically another URL, say /About, to hold another kind of content.

I want /Default and /About share the same header and footer.

I have experience in asp.net webform, where I will write a master page like

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Shared Header</div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
    <div>Shared Fotter</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and each page is like

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    Hello world
</asp:Content>
```

Can I do similar in my current project? I want to keep server side as simple as possible. I don't like IIS Server Side Include because it requires IIS setup. I also want to avoid introducing server side nodejs. However, since I'm already using web api, I don't mind making more use of it.

I foresee all computations needed in my project can be done on client side, and currently they have been done on client side. Therefore if I introduce webform or MVC with empty server side logic, solely for the master page or layout, it seems not economic.

I'm inclined to use client-side solutions. Can AngularJS, ReactJS, VueJS, and sort of frameworks support this? Which one is easiest?

I heard HTML Import as well, but not sure how it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question because all of the frameworks you mentioned are capable of such "master paging". I use Vue.js in my everyday work so I can speak about that but it is only a personal preference.

In Vue.js you can use a "master page" with Vue-Router, you can read about it here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

The main point is that you have to put a router-view tag into your "master page" and the replacement of the content will be managed by the router, based on the navigation (either programmatic by you or triggered by a user interaction).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use angularjs, what I am doing in one of my projects is basically I have one master .cshtml view in my project and this .cshtml includes header, footer, sidebar etc and to this .cshtml I reference all the angularjs controller and each angularjs controller has its own html.

The master view has its own angularjs controller as well.

Now lets suppose the user clicks on an option in the siderbar, lets say "invoice". Upon clicking on invoice, a function gets called in the angularjs controller of master view and that function simply changes the url to /invoice

In my app.js I am using $routeProvider which works like this:-

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/invoice', {
        templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/invoice/template/index.html'
    })
```

so route provider basically changes the html according to the url and the html loaded in the browser has its own angularjs controller